# Xbox 360 HDMI cable?

Tags: xbox-360

Is the Microsoft marketed Xbox 360 cable really any different from the standard HDMI cable?  Is there any reason that I need to get the Microsoft cable or can I just get the standard ($3) cable.

For the record, I'm thinking about the newest generation of Xbox 360, the 4gb model.

Comment: As follow up, I bought the standard $7.99 Amazon HDMI cable and 1) it works a charm and 2) the difference is amazing.  Anyone not using an HDMI cable who can, you really are missing out, even if you have a 15inch TV.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just get the standard cable, there is no real difference between the [$3 Amazon.com cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002L5R78) and [the $800 Best Buy cable](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/AudioQuest+-+Coffee+6.6%27+HDMI+Cable+-+Brown/Black/1267646.p?id=1218245470758&skuId=1267646&st=hdmi&cp=1&lp=8) (make sure you read the reviews on that one).

With digital-signals (unlike analog), **lower-quality signals give you the same quality audio/video.**  HDMI cables *only* carry digital signals, so using *ultra-high quality titanium-shielded solid-gold* cables is no longer necessary to get good-quality audio/video.

Comment: but it sure is fun to watch the boys in blue try to upsell you in the store

Comment: Some more good reviews to read: [65' HDMI cable (made from real copper grain!)](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/AudioQuest+-+Carbon+65.6%27+HDMI+Cable+-+Platinum+White/9892876.p?id=1218202520596&skuId=9892876) - [bi-directional ethernet communications (with Dielectric bias system!)](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/AudioQuest+-+Coffee+39.4%27+HDMI+Cable+-+White/1267764.p?id=1218245464814&skuId=1267764)

Comment: Using *ultra-high quality titanium-shielded solid-gold* cables was never really necessary to get good quality analog signals either.

Comment: It's really disappointing that most big box stores (except perhaps WalMart) don't sell El-Cheapo HDMI cables.

Comment: You forgot "Nitrogen Injected" in your marketroid abuse.

Comment: Do the HDMI cables only do video or do they do audio too?

Comment: @Mechko: HDMI cables carry both *(high definition)* video and *(up to 7.1 surround-sound)* audio

Comment: This is almost but not entirely correct. A poor-quality cable can still introduce electrical interference, and digital/analogue is irrelevant to that. You don't *see* it, but a bad electrical signal means the TV and XBox have to resend a lot of info (it's analogous to high ping times and lots of dropped packets). Worst of all is that the HDMI handshake protocol only allows a fixed number of retries, which means a poor-quality cable can result in intermittent, hard-to-diagnose "no signal" problems on startup. Thankfully, few cables are that bad—but it does happen.

Answer (score 5):

[The Microsoft one comes with an audio dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001S5CCF2) to plug into the back of your 360. This dongle has both analog and optical (digital) TOSLINK connectors on it so you can hook your 360 up to a surround sound system via one of those connections if your receiver doesn't support audio via HDMI (as mine doesn't :( boo).

Outside of that, any HDMI cable will work. Go cheap if you can. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, you can use any HDMI cable. I use one from Monoprice.com [(link)](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10240) that I got for $2-ish.

Cables are where many retailers make money, just like with $50 printer ink cartridges and $2.50 sodas at restaurants. I recommend you never buy any sort of cable at a big-box store. Monoprice and other online stores have just about any cable you could want for less than $3. When I bought my last TV, the store wanted to sell me 6' HDMI cables for *forty dollars* each... unbelievable!