# HDMI cable not working intermittently

Tags: xbox-360, hdmi

My HDMI cable is bipolar: it works, sometimes, if I put the cable just the right way, but otherwise it isn't very reliable. I am using an XBox 360 (not the slim version).

Is it the Xbox or is it the cable? What do i do to fix this trash of a cord?

Comment: If the cable can be forced to perform if you place it just right, that sounds like a short somewhere in the cable. I would try a new HDMI Cable before even thinking about poking around the XBox. 

As for the cable, don't buy something ridiculous. If it costs more than $15, it's ridiculous, related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12139/xbox-360-hdmi-cable?rq=1

Comment: I have a similar issue, and sometimes, it's just a matter of getting it on a good day. Just make sure the connection with the TV/Monitor is solid, then just connect/disconnect on the Xbox until it works.

Comment: Just get a new cable man, see if that works. It's 3 bucks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of 3 possible problems.

1. The HDMI you have is junk and the pins are not matching up properly. Have you tried switching the ends around?
2. The HDMI port on your console is resembles that of a cheap hooker. When plugged in aggressively the pins move and shift.
3. It may be time to replace those faulty X-Clamps MS supplies us with and apply some new thermal paste. If the console is open try turning it on while applying a small amount of pressure on the right heatsink, then left.